# Measuring execution time and memory used

Tags: profiling

Most online judges have some sort of system to measure execution time and memory consumption. An example is shown [here](http://acm.timus.ru/status.aspx). How is it done? Is there a simple UNIX utility I can use to run similar tests on my own programs?

Comment: I work in C and Python. It seems like the measure used by this particular site is programming language agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind with all it's tools will give you some info:

- `cachegrind` - a cache simulator
- `callgrind` - call graph tracing - allows to get the cost of calls and show what is happening in your program
- `massif` - info about heap memory usage
- `memcheck` - memory leak checking

In addition you can use more sophisticated software, like [Intel VTune](http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/239144.htm).

If you are interested in low level details and the real hardware counters yourself then have a look at the [perfmon2](http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/) which has some chances of getting into mainstream kernel some time in the future.

And search old questions - there are many posts on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX [time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)) command will output the amount user time, system time, and some memory statistics.  The Linux version can be found [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/time.1.html) and includes some formatting strings that allow you to specify the exact output.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I needed to profile a Unix program, I used gcc and gprof.  It got me the information I needed.